# Unable to convert String to double Swift

Tags: swift, double

For my app I need to convert a String to a double because I have to create a CLLocationObject for my App and therefore I need those doubles. 
Therefore I tried this:

```
 let lat = (cityObject.lat as! NSString).doubleValue
```

if I print the normal String I get the following:

> some("Optional(52.523553)") some("Optional(13.403783)")

and if I print my double value, I get the following:

> 0.0 0.0

Comment: What is the type of `cityObject.lat`?

Comment: Could you try : Double(cityObject.lat as! NSString) or Double(cityObject.lat) ?

Comment: cityobject.lat is a string and i parse this value from Firebase

Comment: Doule(cityobject.lat as! NSString) doesnt work as well

Comment: I strongly suspect cityObject.lat is not a String.

Comment: and how can i find out which kind of data it is?

Comment: write it's first 2 charaters and look to the type in the autocomplete menu ,,,  write **cityObject.la**

Comment: thats working so its a string

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Please try this:**

```
extension String {
    func toDouble() -> Double? {
        return NumberFormatter().number(from: self)?.doubleValue
    }
}
```

> You can access like that:

```
var myString = "1.2"
var myDouble = myString.toDouble()
```

[image]

> You can remove optional as below:

```
if let data:NSDictionary = snap.value as! NSDictionary,  let lat = data.value(forKey: "lat"),let lng = data.value(forKey: "lng") {
    //then use thes let long to convert in Double

    let latValue = lat.toDouble()
    let lngValue = lng.toDouble()
    }
```

Comment: alue of type 'String' has no member 'toDouble'

Comment: Can you explain it more?

Comment: your code is working but my issue isnt fixed because i found out that i receive an Optional String from my Firebase Database and thats not working with your extension. Do you know how i can remove the Optional Extension?

Comment: it would be great if you could check my code: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49887481/how-to-remove-optional-from-string-value-swift

Comment: @Dominik try `if let dict = snap.value as? [String: Any],
                            let lat = dict["lat"] as? Double,
                            let lng =  dict["lng"] as? Double,
                            let radius = dict["radius"] as? Double {`

Answer (score 1):

`Double` has a failable initializer that takes a `String` and returns an optional `Double?`, since obviously not all `String`s are valid `Double`s.  That means you need to unwrap the result:

```
guard let value = Double("1.0") else {
   print("Not a valid Double")
}
print(value)
```

Comment: Silly error: you missed a *scope exit* inside your `guard` (e.g., `return`, `thow`, etc).

Answer (score -1):

please try below one, it will work perfectly

extension String {

```
var toDoubleVal: Double {

    return Double(self) ?? 0.0
}
```

}